# Redefining section in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I'd like to redefine the `\section` command in `beamer` in such a way that it has the "default" behaviours and additionally creates a slide with a certain shape.

So far, I've tried to code sth like

```
%\newcommand{\oldsection}[1]{\section{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\section}[1]
%{
%   \oldsection{#1}
%   \begin{frame}
%      \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[scheme=esi-blue,shadow=true]{}
%      \begin{center}
%        \LARGE{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}
%       \end{center}
%      \end{beamerboxesrounded}
%   \end{frame}
%}
```

but it doesn't work (looks like some kind of infinite loop. Tries with `\titleformat` failed as well, but I may be using this command wrongly.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It results in an infinite loop, because `\section` expands to `\oldsection` (and other stuff), and `\oldsection` expands again to `\section`. Try `\let\oldsection\section` instead of `\newcommand{\oldsection}[1]{\section{#1}}`.

Comment: Alright, it works fine. Care to explain how what you are doing is different ?

Comment: Consider the definitions `\newcommand\A{X}\newcommand\B{\A}\let\C\A\renewcommand\A{Y}`, and then execute `\A\B\C`. What you will get is `YYX`. `\B` is a macro that contains `\A`, and the contents of `\A` is only used when `\B` is used, therefore `\B` gives `Y`. After `\let\C\A`, on the other hand, `\C` has the same contents as `\A` has, i.e. `X`. When the macro `\A` is later changed to mean `Y`, this does not affect `\C`, but it affects `\B` since it still contains `\A`.

Comment: In your application `\oldsection` effectively refers to the *new* `\section`, since `\oldsection` contains literally the name `\section`, and `\section` is redefined to mean `\oldsection...`. If you use `\let\oldsection\section`, then `\oldsection` gets the current contents of `\section` and will be independent of any redefinition of `\section`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to mess with the `\section` command, beamer itself has mechanism to easily insert section frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\AtBeginSection{%
    \begin{frame}
        \sectionpage
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Blub}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like this layout, just create your own using

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page}{...}
```

Comment: The sad thing with this solution is that it makes all sections behave the same (and for turning this off for some slides only, needs an entire command instead of just a single parameter being empty).